# How to fix "UnauthorizedAccessException" when I try to save image file with C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, file-access

I am using C# and Selenium IWebDriver, I am trying to take a image of the screen and save the file to a folder called "Screenshots" at the project folder level.

I tried to set the access rule for the directory using methodSetAccessRule() 
I want to try other methods other then "SaveAsFile"

```
public class Helper
{
           public static void TakeScreenshot(string value)
        {
            IWebDriver driver;
            driver = DriverFactory.setDriver("Chrome");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(value);
            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
            ss.SaveAsFile(Helper.GetScreenShotDirectory(), ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

        }

        public static string GetScreenShotDirectory()
        {
            string cur = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string screenshotDir = Path.Combine(cur, @"..\..\","Screenshots");
            SetAccessRule(screenshotDir);
            return screenshotDir;
        }

       public static void SetAccessRule(string directory)
        {
            System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity sec = System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(directory);
            FileSystemAccessRule accRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
            sec.AddAccessRule(accRule);
        }
}
```

I expected the SaveAsFile function in takeScreenshot method should save the file in the screenshotDir directory. 
instead I get UnauthorizedAccessException, directory is denied

Comment: Why did I get a down-vote?

Comment: You're trying to overwrite a directory with file content. SaveAsFile takes a fileName parameter, not a directoryPath. REF: [`public void SaveAsFile(string fileName, ScreenshotImageFormat format)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Screenshot_SaveAsFile.htm)

Comment: When I put in fileName as the first parameter it actually replace it with the folder directory,  I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` because you are trying to overwrite your `Screenshots` directory with a .png file.

```cs
// Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver
// Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver -Version 75.0.3770.140
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

namespace Selenium_Screenshot_SaveAsFile
{
    public class DriverFactory
    {
        public static IWebDriver setDriver(string name)
        {
            return new ChromeDriver();
        }
    }

    public class Helper
    {
        public static void TakeScreenshot(string value)
        {
            IWebDriver driver;
            driver = DriverFactory.setDriver("Chrome");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(value);
            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();

            // This succeeds because it's saving to a file...
            ss.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(Helper.GetScreenShotDirectory(), "Hello, world!.png"), ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

            // System.UnauthorizedAccessException because it's trying to overwrite a directory...
            ss.SaveAsFile(Helper.GetScreenShotDirectory(), ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

        }

        public static string GetScreenShotDirectory()
        {
            string cur = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string screenshotDir = Path.Combine(cur, @"..\..\", "Screenshots");
            SetAccessRule(screenshotDir);
            return screenshotDir;
        }

        public static void SetAccessRule(string directory)
        {
            System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity sec = System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(directory);
            FileSystemAccessRule accRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
            sec.AddAccessRule(accRule);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Helper.TakeScreenshot("https://stackoverflow.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1. You're just updating the `DirectorySecurity` in memory, but you aren't saving the permissions back to the directory.

For example, look at the example in the documentation for [Directory.GetAccessControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol):

```
public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
{
    // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

    // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
    // current security settings.
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

    // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                    Rights,
                                                    ControlType));
    // Set the new access settings.
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
}
```

To write the updated permissions back to the file system, it calls [`DirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.setaccesscontrol). You need to do that too. Like this:

```
public static void SetAccessRule(string directory)
{
    var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity sec = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
    FileSystemAccessRule accRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
    sec.AddAccessRule(accRule);

    dInfo.SetAccessControl(sec);
}
```

2. If the account you're runing that with doesn't have permissions to write a file to the directory, would it really have permission to change the permissions? (it's possible... just unlikely)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you mean mean system account? I had admin permission on my windows machine. but anyway let me try this solution

Comment: Yeah, I guess. If the folder you want to write to is in a user's directory, then yeah, I Windows does block Administrators unless you specifically grant yourself access. But it might have to grant itself access to the parent folders first.

Comment: what values do I need to passing AddDirectorySecurity(), where do I get these values, the "SaveAsFile" does not have a file name parameter.

Comment: I updated my answer with changes to your `SetAccessRule` method to match the example in the documentation. You need a `DirectoryInfo` object for the directory.